# Disable odom tf in Fetch Robotics' base_controller

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, base-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a simulated Fetch Robot in gazebo. At startup, it brings up a base controller of type "robot_controllers/DiffDriveBaseController".

How do I stop this from publishing odom tf? I am unable to find any source code for this controller type. I can remove the entire line which brings up this controller, but I want the base to be controlled.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343843/disable-odom-tf-in-fetch-robotics%27-base_controller/) by [sritee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30746/sritee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2020-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first result in Google for `DiffDriveBaseController` leads me to [fetchrobotics/robot_controllers](https://github.com/fetchrobotics/robot_controllers).

This repository contains the source for the [robot_controllers::DiffDriveBaseController](https://github.com/fetchrobotics/robot_controllers/blob/2cab89f872f60712e80d8ed9d64129104738df7a/robot_controllers/src/diff_drive_base.cpp) class, which, as part of its initialisation, reads in a `publish_tf` ROS parameter ([here](https://github.com/fetchrobotics/robot_controllers/blob/2cab89f872f60712e80d8ed9d64129104738df7a/robot_controllers/src/diff_drive_base.cpp#L98)).

There doesn't appear to be any documentation for this controller (the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_controllers) actually points to the API documentation, which doesn't mention any of this), so this is the best I can do.

If this is not sufficient, I would suggest to ask Fetch about this. They should know.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sritee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30746/sritee/) on 2020-02-11**:
publish_tf to false works